# How to persist connection with angular

Tags: angular, authentication, local-storage

I've a small demo app in which I do a fake login.
It works well for my purpose, but I would like to be able to store the user logged in.

I've tried to use the following: But my issue is that when I refresh(F5) the app, the AuthGuard redirects me before the user is retrieved from the the data is taken from the local storage.

I can imagine some scenario to register on my AuthService to see if I'm logged in, to redirect to the default page. But even with this, the user will not stays on the current page.

How to store the user and be able to stay on the same page when refreshing the page?

My AuthService:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from './user.model';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LOCAL_STORAGE, StorageService } from 'ngx-webstorage-service';

const storage_name = 'user-storage';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  private _user = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
  private _isAuth = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  get user(): Observable<User> {
    return this._user.asObservable();
  }
  get isAuth(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._isAuth.asObservable();
  }

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    @Inject(LOCAL_STORAGE) private storage: StorageService
  ) {
    const currentUser = this.storage.get(storage_name) as User;
    if (currentUser) {
      this.setNextUser(currentUser);
    }
  }

  private async setNextUser(user: User) {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)); // To mock service

    console.log('setting next user to ' + user);
    this.storage.set(storage_name, user);
    this._user.next(user);
    this._isAuth.next(user != null);
  }

  async login(username: string, password: string): Promise<boolean> {
    await this.setNextUser({
      name: username,
      avatarUrl: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg',
    });
    return true;
  }
  async logout() {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)); // To mock service
    this.setNextUser(null);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/login');
  }
}
```

The AuthGhuard, if relevant:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { take, tap,  map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
      return this.authService.user.pipe(
        take(1),
        map((user) => !(!user)),
        tap((isLoggedIn) => {
          if (!isLoggedIn) {
            console.log('User is not logged in, redirect to auth')
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth');
          }
        })
      );
  }

}
```

I'm sure there has to be a way?

Comment: rather than calling user, call a method called getUser() which will retrieve the user from the localstorage and return it as an observable. So you can apply a delay() rxjs operator on it to simulate the asynchronous http call.

Comment: @GérômeGrignon Not sure to follow, you would have one method that gets the User from the storage, and my current one that takes the current status? Seems risky, no?

Comment: moving it as a complete answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for initial loading/refresh, you could use APP_INITIALIZER to make operations before the app is loaded and retrieve the user from localstorage this way to put it into the user BehaviorSubject.

Inside AppModule :

```
export function getUserConfig(service: AuthService) {
  return function() {
    const currentUser = localStorage.getItem(storage_name) as User;
    if (currentUser) {
      service.user.next(currentUser);
    }
  }
}

...

providers: [{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    multi: true,
    deps: [AuthService],
    useFactory: getUserConfig
  }],
```

And use your existing `setNextUser()` to update the user;

add the delay rxjs operator to simulate the asynchronous http call :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
      return this.authService.getUser().pipe(
        delay(2000)
        take(1),
        map((user) => !(!user)),
        tap((isLoggedIn) => {
          if (!isLoggedIn) {
            console.log('User is not logged in, redirect to auth')
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth');
          }
        })
      );
  }

}
```

Comment: Okay I see, but then it means that every time I ask the user, it has to go get it in the local storage, true? Wouldn't that be much slower? Also, when I loggin, the Observable of user that you now return(the `of(currentUser)`) will not be triggered, right?

Comment: true, i made a change. I haven't used APP_INITIALIZER for a while so don't hesitate to ask more if it's doesn't work as intended

Comment: I don't know APP_INITIALIZER, but this seems interesting, is it possible to put this in another module than the AppModule(Like my AuthModule) Because I'm trying and the method isn't called.

Comment: i don't know but here is a working stackblitz example based on your need : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yadckp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: I managed to make it work, but it still seems that the AuthGuard is called before. I just didn't include the delay(2000) because there is none(only when login)

Comment: i updated the stackblitz link by adding the authguard with a console.log. You can it being called after APP_INITIALIZER

Comment: I found my bug: The initUser was calling a method on the service(my `setNextUser` above). But this method is async and I was not awaiting it. Thank you very much, it now works with your APP_INITIALIZER